# How to get elements from column of test file

Tags: python

If I have a text file that is in the form of something like this:

column 1   column 2 column 3

Bear          5       10

Turtle        7       5

Snake         9       7

Gorilla       10      8

The goal is to calculate standard deviation of column 2 or 3 depending on what is specified as the argument value the function. I know how to calculate standard deviation so the question is how can i specify which column to use and how can i use/read those values from text file as input to STD formula if they are in column form?

My code so far:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
   for line in f:
      line = line.strip().split(" ")
      print (line)
```

All that this is doing is splitting each entry into a list. But i dont know how to index the second element of each list and add them together. It wont let me

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
from statistics import stdev


def sd(d, column):
    """Calculates SD. Given column can be 0 or 1"""
    return stdev([d[k][column] for k in d.keys()])


d = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if line:
            d[line[0]] = (int(line[1]), int(line[2]))

calculated_sd = sd(d, 0)
```

This should work. The argument column of the function can be either 0 or 1.
What I did was to read the file and store the info into a dictionary, where each animal is a key, and the columns are a tuple associated to the animal's key.
By the way, you should try to code your approach first and then if it doesn't work ask here, not directly ask for the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I edited and added my code.

Comment: You are welcome! If you found this answer useful remember to mark it as a solution for your question. Happy coding!

Comment: Is there any way you could look at my code that i posted in my question. I also edited the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to calculate standard deviation, I guess all you need is to extract the values. Editing a bit your code:

```
def getcolumn(filename, idx):
    cval = []
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            cval.append(line.strip().split()[idx])
    return cval
```

This is a function you can implement in your code. `filename` is a string with the filename, `idx` the index of the column you want to extract (remember indexes start from 0).
`line.strip().split()` is the row converted in a list, so it's enough to insert the index of the colum you want to get the element and append it to `cval`.

Calling the function:

```
values = getcolumn('file.txt', 1)
```

`values` is a list with the values of column 1 of text file. You can use it to calculate the standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you, but why would you append to list if we already have a list to work with?

Comment: It's not the same list. `line.strip().split()` contains a row of the file. `cval` contains the column you need. It's one of the possible ways to extract a column from a text file. Not the only method, but I tried to stay close to the code you provided.